# Using {rms} package for multinomial logit

Tags: r, logistic, multinomial-distribution, rms

Is it possible to use the rms package to model multinomials logits, or elsewise to model several binary logits to achieve the same effect? I am aware that there are many other packages specifically designed to fit multinomial logits, but I am quite attached to the suite in rms.

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but the `multinom` function in the `nnet` is superb. Uses the exact same functionality as any `glm` object (which technically speaking, it is). Aside from preference, what do you need form `rms`?

Comment: Bootstrapped covariance, prediction plots (with prediction intervals), influence statistics, and splines are some of the advantages I'm after. I'm actually using `nnet` and I don't have any issues with it—I think it covers my basic needs very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Having delved into this myself, it appears that it is not possible at the moment. However, it [could be accomplished in the future](https://github.com/harrelfe/rms/issues/11) were someone smarter than me to put some effort into it.